# Meteor Assets not working

Tags: meteor, assets, private

Any file in Meteor private directory app not work. ex:

```
myapp/
      client/
      server/
        main.js
      imports/
        vnc.js
      private/
        bin/
          x11vnc <-----
      public/
```

in /server/main.js

```
import '/imports/vnc.js'
```

in /imports/vnc.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
Meteor.startup(() => {
  x11vncExecutavel = Assets.absoluteFilePath('bin/x11vnc');
})
```

the error is Error: Unknown asset: bin/x11vnc

https://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html

Meteor version is 1.4.3.1

Comment: what else did you try? did you try "/private/bin/x11vnc"?

Comment: According to the documentation: -> "The path of the asset, relative to the application's private subdirectory."

Comment: but what else did you try? e.g. slash in front? did you try .getText() on something in that folder to see if that worked? unless you list all the debugging you did and what happened, we can only assume you tried nothing. you will get a better response if you narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Yes I try whith absolute and relative paths ... .absoluteFilePath, .getText(), getBinary() throw the same error for any file.

Comment: Is x11vnc a file or a directory? I believe this should work: ```x11vncExecutavel = 'assets/bin/x11vnc';```

Comment: This bug is very bizarre, it occurs when I clone git from websockify, when the folder is not there it does not occur, see the video I did demonstrating: https://youtu.be/5Ss7UFBnc_o